# How can I write a file3 with different columns from a matched result queried from file1 to file2?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, text

I have file1.txt and file2.txt with the following structure

File1.txt

```
5511913332222

5511910000023

5511910000029

5511910000034
```

File2.txt

```
5511910000029|BLOCKED|7|30/07/2021 02:19:43

5511910000034|AVAIL|7|30/07/2021 03:11:53

5511910000048|AVAIL|7|30/07/2021 04:10:25

5511910000073|BLOCKED|7|30/07/2021 07:20:33
```

I want to write a file3.txt with the 1st and 2nd columns of the file2 where the 1st column matched  the 1st column of file1.txt.

File3.txt

```
5511910000029|BLOCKED

5511910000034|AVAIL
```

I have tried some tricks with awk but I couldn't get the expected result. Could anyone please help me?

> awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]}NR>FNR && $0 in a{print}' file1 file2 > file3

Comment: Please *show us* your attempts, [so] is not a free code writing service. :) Edit your question and post what you have tried.

Comment: P.S.: `5211810000029`doesn't feature in File1.txt - why do you expect it to be printed?

Comment: @hadesungod `5211910000029` is still not fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} ($1 && $1 in a){print $1,$2}' File1.txt File2.txt 
5511910000034|AVAIL
```

To save output to File3.txt  `... {print $1,$2 > "File3.txt"} ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ join -o 2.1,2.2 -t '|' -j 1 <(sort -k1 -t '|' file1.txt) <(sort -k1 -t '|' file2.txt)
5511910000029|BLOCKED
5511910000034|AVAIL
```

This means `join` on the first field in both files (`-j 1`), outputting (`-o`) the first and second fields (`.1`, `.2`) of the second file (`2.`), using bar as a field delimiter (`-t '|'`), and sorting the inputs (`<(sort)`) on the first field (`-k1`) with bar as a delimiter (`-t '|' again).

This assumes that `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` 1) aren't already sorted; 2) can be sorted; 3) don't have every other line blank, like you show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the lines in *file1* consist of only digits, you can verify that using `$0 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/` before setting them as a key in `a`

Set the output field separator to `|` and set the field separator of *file2* also to `|`

```
awk -v OFS="|" '
NR==FNR && $0 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {
  a[$0]
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $1,$2
}
' file1  FS="|" file2 > file3
```

The content of *file3*:

```
5511910000029|BLOCKED
5511910000034|AVAIL
```